# Git: does ffwd merge preserves all topic branch commits?

Tags: git, merge, commit, preserve, fast-forward

Say we have this situation:

```
       master
         |
A--B--B--D--E--F--G
                  |
                test
```

Then we merge test into master. Are commits E and F preserved in the new master branch?

That is, does it now lok like this (option A):

```
                master
                  |
A--B--B--D--E--F--G
                  |
                test
```

or like this (option B):

```
          master
            |
A--B--B--D--G
            |
          test
```

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find it. Also, the example in ProGit book is with only one commit ahead (in my example that would be E), which doesn't tackle a situation like this.

Comment: It sounds like you're horribly confused about how commits work. E and F cannot possibly be dropped without actually changing G (and its SHA1).

Comment: Not in sense that they are dropped, like never done... but rather "forgotten" from history. Of course they are foundations of G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens it **option A**: commits are preserved. In case of a fast-forward merge the history is not modified at all, only the `master` branch points at a different commit. That's all.

Comment: Thanx! It made sense that way, but still I felt urge to ask... maybe I'm just too curious :-)

Answer (score 1):

You get a fast forward merge (option A) and the reason to begin with is because there is only a single line of commits between master and test before the merge. If there was a branch between master and test, it would not be a fast forward merge any more.

I would suggest reading [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for a good overview on how branching and merging works in git - you need to be really clear on how this stuff works when using git.

Comment: ProGit is of course the primary literature. Only in this section there is only one commit ahead of master (C3), and in ffwd merge it can not be forgotten. But the chapter didn't cover situation with several commits ahead of master, that's why I asked. Just to make sure. Thanx!

Comment: @Martin Think about it this way - a fast forward merge is nothing but moving the master branch pointer forward until it is at the same position as the test branch pointer. If you can, then git will do it :)

Comment: Yup, got it! Only wording is a BIT confusing - the pointer goes forward in terms of time, from earlier commits to more recent ones. But if you follow the commit pointers strictly, they point in the opposite direction - towards ancestor, so if we follow the pointers strictily - it's actually a REWIND merge. Isn't it?

Comment: No.  As stated in your other question, newer commits are added on at the end.  The arrows point to where you have come from, not where you're going.

Answer (score 1):

Option A is what happens. Sometimes people want to preserve the branch point and will force git to create a new merge commit.

```
git merge --no-ff test
```

This depends on the workflow you want to follow for development.